# Error handling of user information in Unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to do some error handling in the beginning of a script.  If a user is not a member of a specific group then the script needs to exit.

Comment: `chgrp <targetgroup> <myscript>; chmod uo-x,g+x <myscript>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
group=wheel
if groups | grep -q "\b$group\b"; then
  echo member
else
  echo "no member"
  exit 1
fi
```

or shorter:

```
group=wheel
groups | grep -q "\b$group\b" || exit 1
```